# Error with floating point literal in Scala REPL

Tags: scala, floating-point, literals, read-eval-print-loop, scala-repl

The definiton for floating point literal in Scala is

```
floatingPointLiteral  ::=  digit {digit} ‘.’ digit {digit} [exponentPart] [floatType]
                        |  ‘.’ digit {digit} [exponentPart] [floatType]
                        |  digit {digit} exponentPart [floatType]
                        |  digit {digit} [exponentPart] floatType
exponentPart          ::=  (‘E’ | ‘e’) [‘+’ | ‘-’] digit {digit}
floatType             ::=  ‘F’ | ‘f’ | ‘D’ | ‘d’
```

When I try to input floating point literal that starts with a dot I get an error:

```
scala> .123
        ^
   error: ';' expected but double literal found.
```

If is assign such literal to some variable everything is fine

```
scala> val x = .123
x: Double = 0.123
```

Why it behaves like that?

Comment: Why do you need to write any number in Scala console without any assignation or returning? This number just has no means.

Comment: Or use ammonite which is way better Scala REPL than vanilla REPL. It handles this case correctly.

Comment: Do you also want `digit {digit} ‘.’ [exponentPart] [floatType]`?  Is "123.e45" not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the quote you pasted is from the [Syntax Summary](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/13-syntax-summary.html).

Before we answer your question, let's notice the following:

```
scala> 1.213
res1: Double = 1.213
```

So the issue here is not the floating point, but the fact that the expression starts with a dot. It makes the console, just like a regular Scala program, to evaluate the expression on the last object calculated.

Let's do an example:

```
scala> val d = 1.123
d: Double = 1.123

scala> .equals(1.123)
res10: Boolean = true

scala> .equals(1.123)
res11: Boolean = false

scala> .toString
res12: String = false
```

As you can see, every new line, is a follow up of the previous. You can go back, for example:

```
scala> res10
res13: Boolean = true
```

But the object in cache is the last result.

In your example, probably the last successful run of your console was `val x = .123`, which put the last `res` as a `Double`. When you ran `.123` you are starting another `BlockStat`. The lexer identifies it is a `Block`, and therefore expects a `semi` (which is a `;`) between the different `BlockStat`s.

When starting a new console, it works as expected:

```
scala> .123
res0: Double = 0.123
```